# Can't edit settings.php in Drupal 7 - Premission Denied - Can't Write to File via Cpanel File Manager

Tags: files, configuration

Trying to edit settings.php via Cpanel File Manager

I can CHMOD the file to anything I want and back but can't write to it.

I get the following message:

> Could not write /home/testing/public_html/sites/default/settings.php: Permission denied

Do you think Apache suEXEC has anything to do with this?

Comment: This is server side issue not Drupal related. You need to check permission for `sites`, `default` and `settings.php` file.

Comment: settings.php is write-protected. You can change the permissions to make it writable, but Drupal will change it back on the first page load, and set it write-protected again.  So you should make any change in the settings.php without visiting your site after changing the permissions.

Comment: sites/default folder permission setting is 555, is that correct?  What should it be?

Comment: @ShaneHouston ask your sysadmin. Webserver that runs Drupal must be able to enter it and all it's subfolders, read everything there, and write & delete in files subfolder. How to set that up depends on your server's configuration.

Comment: sites/defualt permission should be 755

Comment: @ShaneHouston, `sites/default` permission should be 755 as mentioned by Mohammad Shameem.

Answer (score 13):

As others have mentioned, you must set the permissions on the `/sites/default` folder. The default permissions are set to `0555`, set them to `0755` for editing. Don't forget to restore the default values afterwards!

Comment: Thanks, I had to set permission 755 on sites folder first, then the default and finally on the files in it in order to be able to delete it all.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend to download the file on your local system if you can. Right click on the **settings.php** file and select **Properties** from the list. Uncheck the **Read-only** from **Attributes**. Click apply button and click OK. Make changes and upload the file back to the server.

NOTE: After editing the file Check the **Read-only** attribute before uploading.

[image]

Comment: Works. Remember that Drupal add Read-only back again as soon as Drupal is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the **permissions** of the folder it self.
The folder "**default**" set to 0555, set them to 0755 for editing. Don't forget to restore the default values afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this issue in the future, add the following line to your `settings.php` file:

```php
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;
```

This will prevent Drupal from re-enabling the read-only status of the `/sites/default` directory and the `settings.php` within. Drupal will no longer configure the permissions itself.